# calculating current draw for opamp circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, current, audio, current-measurement, power-consumption

I am trying to understand how to estimate the current drawn by the following opamp circuit and how much current the regulators for the +14/-14 rails should be able to deliver.

The opamp used is the NE5532. I've drawn the circuit in TINA-TI, and loaded the [NE5532 spice model](http://www.beis.de/Elektronik/Filter/NE553x.lb) and then ran a transient analysis. The input signals for the circuit are sine waves with amplitude 2.8Vpp around 5V. When I zoom in on the plot I can see a steady current draw of 2.2mA on both the +14V and -14V rails.

Is this correct and realistic, and can I use that as a basis to determine how much current my regulators for the rails should be able to deliver?

[image]

Comment: What does the data sheet say? Have you read it? If not, why not?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast it says that total supply current, Icc, is typically 8mA and max 16mA... if I assume that this is for both rails and the 2 opamps in the package together, for the typical figure I guess that gives 2mA per opamp, so that would make sense, but it doesn't specify that.

Comment: constant 2mA seems wrong, a typical op-amp gets its output current from the supply rails.  By the way, what's the purpose of R2 ?

Comment: @jasen R2 is for impedance matching

Comment: that's not what R2 is doing. it's only connected to a simulated voltmeter,  (so it's in series with an infinite resistor) simulating this circuit without a load will give misleading results. (assuming I'm reading VM1's symbol correctly)

Comment: @jasen you are right, my mistake. I corrected the circuit and connected R2 to ground... i'll update the schematic

Comment: I'd be inclined to believe that now